# i got error about python TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, mysql, uart

Hi i'm doing my school project but i got a problem in Python programming.
This is the source of my program. 
It says

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

what is the problem do you think?..
please give me a hand. Thank you.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from Tkinter import *
import time
import serial
import MySQLdb

i = 3

ser = serial.Serial(
port='/dev/ttyAMA0',
baudrate=9600,
parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
timeout=1
)

db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "1234", "project")
curs = db.cursor()

def update_timeText():
    current = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    timeText.configure(text=current)
    root.after(1000, update_timeText)

def update_db():
    global i
    x = ser.readline()
    if len(x) == 8:
        while x:
            if i == 20:
                i = 3
            Label(root, text= x, font=("Helvetica", 20), bg = 'white').grid(row=i,column=3)
            curs.execute("select name from matchdata where rfid = %s", (x))
            currentname = curs.fetchone()
            Label(root, text= currentname[0], font=("Helvetica", 20), bg = 'white').grid(row= i, column=0, columnspan=2)
            curs.execute("select sex from matchdata where rfid = %s", (x))
            currentsex = curs.fetchone()
            Label(root, text= currentsex, font=("Helvetica", 20), bg = 'white').grid(row=i, column=2)
            curs.execute("insert into readdata values(NOW(), %s)",(x))
            db.commit()
            i = i+1
            break;
    else:
        print "UART ERROR"
    root.after(10, update_db)

root = Tk()

root.configure(background='white')
logo = PhotoImage(file="logo.gif")
Label(root,image=logo).grid(row=0,column=0, rowspan = 1, columnspan = 4, sticky=W)

Label(root,text="< NAME >", font=("Helvetica",30), bg='white').grid(row= 2, column=0,columnspan=2)
Label(root,text="< SEX >", font=("Helvetica",30), bg='white').grid(row= 2, column=2, columnspan=1)
Label(root,text="< RFID >", font=("Helvetica",30), bg = 'white').grid(row= 2, column=3,columnspan=1)
timeText = Label(root,text="",font=("Helvetica",45),bg='white')
timeText.grid(row=0, column=3)
timeText.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
timeText.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
update_timeText()
update_db()
root.mainloop()

curs.close()
db.close()
```

Comment: Well could you please post the line where the error occurs? And did you do any research of the error by your self?

Comment: Hi! Please post your full error code

Answer (score 1):

Vague question - vague answer: Somwhere (exactly where the exception traceback tells you) you access an object in this way: `something[index]`. Maybe it is `currentname[0]`.

In your case, `currentname` (or whatever it is) is `None`, so an access with `[0]` is not possible and you get the said exception.

Comment: Then i should do just  Label(root, text= currentname, font=("Helvetica", 20), bg = 'white').grid(row= i, column=0, columnspan=2) ??

Comment: @AlexJung Well, I am not sure. Till now, you didn't edit the question for adding the full exception including the traceback, so no one can be sure where exactly the error occurred. Try it, tell us if it helps, and if doesn't, add more info as requested.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `curs.execute` takes a tuple as its second argument. Your `(x)` still evaluates to just `x`, not a tuple containing `x`. Try `(x,)`, which is the correct syntax for a tuple containing a single element.

Comment: But if this was the problem (`x` being `None`), the `len(x) == 8` check would already have failed.

Comment: The problem isn't that `x` is `None`; the problem is that `(x)` is supposed to be `(x,)`, which is probably what's resulting in `currentname` being set to `None`. Since `x` is most likely a string, `curs.execute` treats it as an tuple and uses only its first character, rather than the whole string, as the value being interpolated into the query. So the OP is really querying for `rfid = '1'` instead of `rfid = '12345678'`, hence `fetchone` returns `None`.

Comment: Then i just can change into this? curs.execute("select name from matchdata where rfid = %s", (x,)) and curs.execute("select sex from matchdata where rfid = %s", (x,))??

Comment: Correct. Let us know if that resolves the issue. Don't forget about `curs.execute("insert into readdata values(NOW(), %s)",(x,))`.

Comment: I will try today and see how it works! Thank you for your opinion!